# On Minkowski Reduction of Quadratic Forms

Tags: quadratic-forms, positive-definite

A positive definite quadratic form $q(x)=x^TQx$ (assume $Q$ is symmetric) is said to be Minkowski reduced if for all $1\leq k\leq n$ we that any $x\in \mathbb{Z}^n$ with $GCD(x_k,\ldots,x_n)=1$ has $q(x)\geq q(e_k)$ .

I wonder if for any Minkowski reduced form we can replace $GCD(x_k,\ldots,x_n)=1$ by $GCD(x_k,\ldots,x_n)\geq 1$? In other words, is there a positive definite quadratic form of any dimension that is Minkowski reduced but such that the following does not hold: for any $x\in \mathbb{Z}^n$ with $GCD(x_k,\ldots,x_n)\geq 1$ we have $q(x)\geq q(e_k)$ for all $1\leq k\leq n$?

I think I have been able to show that such an example does not exist. However, based on a few things I have read, I have a suspicion that they do exist.

Answer (score 2):

The lattice of the following basis is Minkowski reduced,

$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1/2\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1/2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1/2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 \end{bmatrix}.$

However, $e_5\in A\mathbb{Z}^n$ despite the fact that $|e_5|< a_5$ where $a_5$ is the fifth vector of $A$. This is therefore a counterexample.